# Error: Cannot find module 'camelcase'

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, gulp, debian, gulp-sass

I'm trying to run a gulp based application.
On Ubuntu, everything is working, but on Debian server not.

Ubuntu: npm: 5.3.0, nodejs: v8.2.1, bower@1.8.0, gulp-cli@1.4.0, npm@5.3.0

Debian: npm: 5.3.0, nodejs: v8.2.1, bower@1.8.0, gulp-cli@1.4.0, npm@5.3.0

Gulpfile:

```
'use strict';

const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('scss2css', function () {
    gulp.src(['./web/scss/style.scss'])
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./web/css/'));
});

gulp.task('scss2css:watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./scss/**/*.scss', ['scss2css']);
});

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.start('scss2css');
});
```

When I type "gulp", I receive message like below:

```
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'camelcase'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/node_modules/yargs/lib/parser.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

Comment: On Ubuntu v8.2.1 still working

Comment: So it seems you need to install _camelcase_ module on your Debian server.

Comment: after npm install -g camelcase gulp-camelcase still not working

Answer (score -1):

I just removed nodejs package and directories:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```